# Update Data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, helper

My code is this

```
Profile.update_all(["is_active = ?, name = ?, geo_lat = ?, geo_long = ?, radius = ?, search_option = ?", 1, params[:profile_name],'null','null','null','st'])
```

but it assign

> geo_lat=0

and

> geo_long=0

In my database structure default value is null for both
and i want to assign null
please help me

Comment: Try this

    `Profile.update_all(["is_active = ?, name = ?, geo_lat = ?, geo_long = ?, radius = ?, search_option = ?", 1, params[:profile_name],nil, nil, nil,'st'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here are string 'null'.

Try the following:

```
Profile.update_all(["is_active = ?, name = ?, geo_lat = ?, geo_long = ?, radius = ?, search_option = ?", 1, params[:profile_name], nil, nil, nil, 'st'])
```

Also check your migration to see if default is not set to string 'null'.